# How to set the tolerance of expect_equal in testthat framework

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I would like to know if it is possible in R using `testthat` test framework to set the tolerance for equality.

Currently, if `example.R` is:

```
library(testthat)
three_times<-function(x) 3*x

context('Test three_times')
test_that('Three times returns 3 times x',{
    expect_equal(three_times(3),9)
    expect_equal(three_times(pi),9.4247)
})
```

and executed with `test_file('example.R','stop')`, the first test passes, but the second fails with:

```
 Error: Test failed: 'Three times returns 3 times x'
Not expected: three_times(pi) not equal to 9.4247
Mean relative difference: 8.271963e-06.
```

Is it possible to set a higher error threshold for the mean relative difference? for example  1e-3. I have some expected results with only a 3 decimal precision, meaning now my tests always fail...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can pass arguments `scale` or `tolerance`. These arguments are passed to `all.equal`.

```
expect_equal(three_times(pi),9.4247, tolerance=1e-8)
Error: three_times(pi) not equal to 9.4247
Mean relative difference: 8.271963e-06

expect_equal(three_times(pi),9.4247, tolerance=1e-3)
```

See `?all.equal` for more help

Comment: And you _must_ name `tolerance=` as from testthat 0.10.1 on CRAN May 2015.  i.e. `expect_equal(pi*3, 9.4247, 1e-3)` no longer works and must be `expect_equal(pi*3, 9.4247, tolerance=1e-3)`